# how to solve Firebase API initialization failure in android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

the problem is whenever I open cart button it is showing this error and also one more problem is that how to change file type in android because in assets I created a directory named databases and in that I added a file BuyItDB with .db extension but by mistake I pressed the file type as database and then onwards I am getting an error as UTF not correct. Can you please help me regarding this error. Thank You.

The dependencies are:

```
dependencies {

    //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']

    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This is the code of the database.java :

```
package com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela.Database;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela.Model.Order;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "BuyItDB.sqlite";
    private static  final int DB_VER = 1;


     public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME,null, DB_VER);
    }


    public List<Order> getCarts(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = {"ProductId","ProductName","Quantity","Price","Discount"};
        String sqlTable = "OrderDetails";

        qb.setTables(sqlTable);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null,null,null,null,null);

        final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                result.add(new Order(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                 c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Discount"))
                        ));

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void addToCart(Order order){

        SQLiteDatabase db =getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetails(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES ('&ProductId','&ProductName','&Quantity','&Price','&Discount');",
                order.getProductId(),
                order.getProductName(),
                order.getQuantity(),
                order.getPrice(),
                order.getDiscount());
            db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void cleanCart(){

        SQLiteDatabase db =getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("DELETE FROM OrderDetails");
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

This the error that is displaying in logcat:

```
  06-15 08:30:27.476 5841-5841/com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: OrderDetail
06-15 08:30:27.476 5841-5841/com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-15 08:30:27.480 5841-5841/com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela, PID: 5841
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela/com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela.Cart}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: OrderDetail (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ProductId, ProductName, Quantity, Price, Discount FROM OrderDetail
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: OrderDetail (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ProductId, ProductName, Quantity, Price, Discount FROM OrderDetail
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
        at com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela.Database.Database.getCarts(Database.java:32)
        at com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela.Cart.loadListCar(Cart.java:115)
        at com.example.saikrishna.gaadimela.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: You probably should not use classes from a package called `internal`...

Comment: Can you post your app-level `build.gradle`? This looks like a Firebase dependency problem, not SQLite.

Comment: implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

Comment: instead of posting that in the comments, please *edit* this information into your question

Comment: Please don't completely change a question to ask a new problem. Do you still get the same error when you completely uninstall and re-install the app? It's looking for table called `OrderDetail` (without an `s` at the end) but all instances of your table name are correct in `Database.java`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** This answer covers [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50856550/4) as OP has completely changed the question since then.

You have a version mismatch for your firebase dependencies. This is what you currently have:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
```

`firebase-core` and `firebase-ui-database` are old versions, while `firebase-database` is up to date. As a result, `firebase-database` is expecting methods from `firebase-core` that may not be there or may not work as intended. You can fix this by updating to the [latest versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.1'
```